# Single 'load from datastore' method for supertype usable when used as subtype

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two classes, `Person` and `Employee`. `Employee` extends `Person`.

I have a method that reads a `Person` from storage, and am writing the method that reads an `Employee`.

I'd like to reuse the method I have for `Person` to read the properties that are the same for `Employee`, without copy-pasting the code, but can't seem to find a way to do it.

```
public Person getPersonFromStorage() {
    Person person = new Person();
    // ... logic
    return person;
}

public Employee getEmployeeFromStorage() {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    // ... logic for employee-specific fields

    // I want to read the fields inherited from Person here
    return employee;
}
```

I cannot cast the retrieved `Person` from `getPersonFromStorage`, because it is not an `Employee`. It could be, because it's not another subtype either, but it's not.

I could do the following:

```
public Person getPersonFromStorage(Person person) {
    if(person==null) { person = new Person(); }
    // ... logic
    return person;
}

public Employee getEmployeeFromStorage() {
    Employee employee = (Employee) getPersonFromStorage(new Employee());
    // ... logic for employee-specific fields
    return employee;
}
```

But I'd like to avoid this complexity if I can. I have the feeling I'm overlooking something elementary. Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just offering a different architecture that I usually use in this instance. If you're talking about "from storage", to me that means some sort of persistent structure. Text File, database, etc. For the following example, let's assume you have your values in a text file.

Assume a file `employees.txt`, which contains one employee:

```
// Dave's person details.
Dave
Manchester
32
// Dave's employee details
Assassin
Mostly North Korea.
```

Then you've got a class `Person`, that looks a little like this:

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, String location, int age)
    {
       // blah blah blah.
    }
}
```

And a class `Employee` that looks like this:

```
public class Employee extends Person
{
    private String jobTitle;
    private String area;

    public Employee() { 
       // etc.
    }
}
```

In your `Person` class, you can create a constructor designed to read the parameters for a `Person`. Something like:

```
public Person(Scanner file)
{
    this.name = file.nextLine();
    this.location = file.nextLine();
    this.age = file.nextInt();
    file.nextLine(); // Make sure you're pointing at the new line!
}
```

And in your `Employee` class, you can create a constructor designed to read the parameters for an employee, while calling it's superclass to deal with the other values.

```
public Employee(Scanner file)
{
    super(file);
    this.jobTitle = scanner.nextLine();
    this.area = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Then all you have to do to call this is something like:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("employees.txt");
Person p = new Employee(s);
```

or to make it more compact:

```
Person p = new Employee(new Scanner("employees.txt"));
```

This will go and parse the file, and return an object, while wrapping up all the logic for actually *reading* the file inside the classes that need the data.

**Not a text file?**

Well, it's not really vital. The important thing is just passing an object up the call chain, and those methods are doing what *that particular class* needs to do, then passing on the object. If it's a `database row`, it's exactly the same principle.

Comment: Interesting take! Thing is that for implementation reasons I really can't have data storage-specific logic in my constructor.

Comment: You could always port the logic out to a different class structure. I've just always liked the idea of putting the logic in the constructor. That way the constructor is actually *building* the class in the way it is supposed to.

Comment: I don't really see how I'd port it to different classes, other than copy-/paste with a different name, which, to be fair, is not as bad as I make it sound. If I'd do it in one class, it becomes awfully similar to my proposed solution.

Comment: Can you not add methods to the `Person` and `Employee` class? The methods would appear in each class, but the actual code in those methods wouldn't ever repeat, because you're only parsing the lines *for that particular class*.

Comment: I have several storage implementation options, and the model shouldn't know about them. I'm thinking to implement a layer between model and storage this way though. That's what I meant with copy-/paste under a different name, you'd get something like `SomeStorageEmployeeController`.

Comment: You could mimic the hierarchy of the model classes, in your data access layer. `PersonController` is a superclass of `EmployeeController`, etc. No code repetition, and easy to follow design?

Answer (score 1):

Your second code example is the way to go, except you don't even need the `null` check line. Just pass in a non-null `Person` that you've instantiated elsewhere.

For even better abstraction, see if you can make `Person` into an `abstract` class.

Comment: The get methods currently take a DAO as parameter. In my casus I'd prefer this way, but your point is valid. `Person` also serves an important purpose in my architecture by itself, so making it abstract doesn't have my favor either, but good point!

I just hoped for something better than I already had :P.

Answer (score 1):

More elegant way is to overload `Employee` constructor to be able to create `Employee` instance from parent `Person` instance.

```
public Employee getEmployeeFromStorage() {
    Employee employee = new Employee(getPersonFromStorage());
    // ... logic for employee-specific fields
    return employee;
}
```

Comment: Thought about that! It would be more elegant here, but it would mean I have to include calls to all `Person` getters and setters in said constructor. Which I have to edit if I edit the `Person` class.

Comment: @MarkTielemans, you can call `Person` constructor using `super` so you should provide only `Employee`-specific fields.

Comment: So I define a `Person` constructor with all its fields, or even something like `public Person(Person person) { this = person }`?

Comment: @MarkTielemans, it is not exactly wht I mean. I can make answer more definitive if you provide more information about properties of this classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a protected factory method.

```
protected Person createNewInstance() { return new Person(); }
```

and use this in your getPersonFromStorage() method. The subclass would then override this method, thus changing the return type into an Employee, which you can then use like in your second example.

```
public class Person {

    public Person getPersonFromStorage() {
        Person person = createNewInstance();
        // ... logic
        return person;
    }

    protected Person createNewInstance() {
        return new Person();
    }
}

public class Employee extends Person {

    public Employee getEmployeeFromStorage() {
        Employee employee = (Employee) getPersonFromStorage();
        // ... logic for employee-specific fields
        return employee;
    }

    protected Person createNewInstance() {
        return new Employee();
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you could also create an Employee constructor based on a Person

```
public class Employee extends Person {
    public Employee(Person person) {
        super();
        // copy all fields from person 
    }

    public static Employee getEmployeeFromStorage() {
        Employee employee = new Employee(getPersonFromStorage());
        // ... logic for employee-specific fields
        return employee;
    }
}
```

I also added static to the methods, assuming you're intending to create new instances with no direct relationship to existing objects. This would not work with the first variant.